# How can I take a photo using a slow shutter speed without it being overexposed?

Tags: shutter-speed, overexposure

When I try to take a picture using a slow shutter speed in daylight it is overexposed. How can I change the settings so it isn't overexposed?

Comment: Also: [long exposure shot - subject too bright](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/55849/long-exposure-shot-subject-too-bright)

Comment: And: [How can I depict vehicle traffic during daytime in a long exposure without washing out the vehicles?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/42981/how-can-i-depict-vehicle-traffic-during-daytime-in-a-long-exposure-without-washi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the followings:

1. Switch to Manual Control - This will immediately enable you control the aperture. Shoot, review the picture in the light setting you are about to take the actual shot. Increase the aperture e.g. from f/8 to f/11 or f/16 until you get the required exposure
2. Switch auto ISO to manual - Make sure your ISO is not set to auto. If you are still getting over exposed shots with the step 1 (manual exposure), try to reduce ISO e.g. from ISO 400 to min allowed ISO in your camera e.g. ISO 100
3. Block the light - Try blocking the light coming to your camera - either use something to reduce the light or try chaning your position to the subject. Sometimes, all we need is to change the position and the exposure falls in place.
4. Use ND filter - If none of the above works, use Neutral density filters as suggested by someone above.

Answer (score 10):

You can close down the aperture and lower the ISO. This will help only up to a point.

After that, what you need is a [Neutral-Density (ND)](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/71793/15871) filter. Those filters serve to reduce the amount of light reaching the sensor. They vary in strength. An ND4 for example, lets pass 1/4 of the light, so allows exposure 2 stops longer in shutter-speed. You can even get an ND400 or more now. With such a filter you can photograph the sun since it reduces incoming light by 400X.

ND Filters are commonly used to take long exposures during the day time to get motion blur during daylight. They can also be used at night to get longer star-trails.